# how to create "pretty" numbers?

Tags: php, algorithm, numbers, usability

my question is: is there a good (common) algorithm to create numbers, which match well looking user understood numbers out of incomming (kind of random looking for a user) numbers.

i.e. you have an interval from

`130'777.12 - 542'441.17`.

But for the user you want to display something more ...say userfriendly, like:

`130'000 - 550'000`.

how can you do this for several dimensions?
an other example would be:

`23.07 - 103.50` to `20 - 150`

do you understand what i mean?

i should give some criteria as well:

- the interval min and max should
  include the given limits.
- the "rounding" should be in a
  granularity which reflects the
  distance between min and max (meaning
  in our second example `20 - 200`
  would be too coarse)

very much honor you'll earn if you know a native php function which can do this :-)

*update - 2011-02-21 *

I like the answer from @Ivan and so accepted it. Here is my solution so far:

maybe you can do it better. i am open for any proposals ;-).

```
/**
 * formats a given float number to a well readable number for human beings
 * @author helle + ivan + greg
 * @param float $number 
 * @param boolean $min regulates wheter its the min or max of an interval
 * @return integer
 */
function pretty_number($number, $min){
    $orig = $number;
    $digit_count = floor(log($number,10))+1; //capture count of digits in number (ignoring decimals)
    switch($digit_count){
        case 0: $number = 0; break;
        case 1:
        case 2: $number = round($number/10) * 10; break;
        default: $number = round($number, (-1*($digit_count -2 )) ); break;
    }

    //be sure to include the interval borders
    if($min == true && $number > $orig){
        return pretty_number($orig - pow(10, $digit_count-2)/2, true);
    }

    if($min == false && $number < $orig){
        return pretty_number($orig + pow(10, $digit_count-2)/2, false);
    }

    return $number;

}
```

Comment: Maybe add some more examples? People seem to have trouble seeing what this is about

Comment: i think so too. have researched some days and nothing found.

Comment: Please explain your question more clearly: why do you want to round 23.07–103.50 to 20–150 and not to 20–105 or 20–110 or 10–110 or 0–120 or 0–150 etc.? What exactly is your criterion for numbers being "pretty"? Once you're clear about what you want, the solution should present itself.

Comment: @ShreevastaR well, i don't really know that. It should just be globally userfriendly ;-) ... too little steps would be not so pretty for me (20 - 105).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use Log10 to find how "long" the number is and then round it up or down.  Here's a quick and dirty example.

```
echo prettyFloor(23.07);//20
echo " - ";
echo prettyCeil(103.50);//110

echo prettyFloor(130777.12);//130000
echo " - ";
echo prettyCeil(542441.17);//550000

function prettyFloor($n)
{
  $l = floor(log(abs($n),10))-1; // $l = how many digits we will have to nullify :)
  if ($l<=0)
    $l++;

  if ($l>0)
    $n=$n/(pow(10,$l)); //moving decimal point $l positions to the left eg(if $l=2 1234 => 12.34 )
  $n=floor($n);
  if ($l>0)
    $n=$n*(pow(10,$l)); //moving decimal point $l positions to the right eg(if $l=2 12.3 => 1230 )
  return $n;
}

function prettyCeil($n)
{
  $l = floor(log(abs($n),10))-1;
  if ($l<=0)
    $l++;
  if ($l>0)
    $n=$n/(pow(10,$l));
  $n=ceil($n);
  if ($l>0)
    $n=$n*(pow(10,$l));
  return $n;
}
```

This example unfortunately will not convert 130 to 150. As both 130 and 150 have the same precision. Even thou for us, humans 150 looks a bit "rounder". In order to achieve such result I would recommend to use quinary system instead of decimal.

Comment: i also thought about using logarithm. maybe i can use it together with that `round(x,r)` thing ...

Comment: Indeed you could. just put round($n, -(floor(log($n,10))-1)).  However in this case you cannot be sure that initial range is a subset of rounded range eg 99-201 will be rounded to 100-200

Comment: @Ivan: about two years ago, but I'll give it a try: How to make numbers < 0 pretty? log10 isn't doing the job here...

Comment: @michi  good catch. Indeed we should take logarithm of absolute value in order to avoid dealing with imaginary numbers. I'll update the solution in a sec

Answer (score 4):

You can use php's `round` function which takes a parameter to specify the precision.

```
<?php
echo round(3.4);         // 3
echo round(3.5);         // 4
echo round(3.6);         // 4
echo round(3.6, 0);      // 4
echo round(1.95583, 2);  // 1.96
echo round(1241757, -3); // 1242000
echo round(5.045, 2);    // 5.05
echo round(5.055, 2);    // 5.06
?>
```

Comment: Not really what the OP is asking for - the issue at hand is formatting two numbers depending on their size, and the size of the difference between them. Much more difficult than just rounding

Comment: that seems like a good approach `round(1241757, -3);` . but the next problem is, how to find out the seocnd parameter? one upvote from me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The [`number_format()`](http://php.net/number_format) function handles "prettifying" numbers with arbitrary thousands/decimal characters and decimal places, but you'd have to split your ranges/strings into individual numbers, as number_formation only works on one number at a time.

The rounding portion would have to handled seperately as well.

Comment: The issue is rather "how to work out what precision to use for which interval?"

Comment: Yeah, round to what level for what 'size' number.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen ready algorithm or function for that. But it should be simple, based on string replacement (`str_replace`, `preg_replace`), `number_format` and `round` functions.

Answer (score 0):

This actually is kind of a special case, that can be addressed with the following function:

```
function roundto($val, $toceil=false) { 
    $precision=2; // try 1, 2, 5, 10 
    $pow = floor(log($val, 10)); 
    $mult = pow(10, $pow);
    $a = $val/$mult*$precision; 
    if (!$toceil) $a-=0.5; else $a+=0.5; 
    return round($a)/$precision*$mult; 
}

$v0=130777.12; $v1=542441.17; 
echo number_format(roundto($v0, false), 0, '.', "'").' - '
    .number_format(roundto($v1, true), 0, '.', "'").'<br/>';

$v0=23.07; $v1=103.50; 
echo number_format(roundto($v0, false), 0, '.', "'").' - '
    .number_format(roundto($v1, true), 0, '.', "'").'<br/>';
```

Outputs exactly this:

```
100'000 - 550'000
20 - 150
```

For any other case of number formatting it might be interesting to have a look at my newly published PHP class "[php-beautiful-numbers](https://github.com/SirDagen/php-beautiful-numbers)", which I use in almost ever project to display run times ("98.4 µs" [= 9.8437291615846E-5]) or numbers in running text (e.g. "you booked two flights." [= 2]).

https://github.com/SirDagen/php-beautiful-numbers